# How can I merge two python project with similar project structure into one project?

Tags: python

Here is the question, I got two python project, Project A and Project B, Here is the struct of Project A:

/Project_A 
    /__init__.py 
    /a.py 
    /main.py

and the code in main.py like:

```
from a import func

def main():
    func()
```

Now I assume Project_B is has extraly the same structure and same code in main.py 
The only differences of Project_A and Project_B is the method func, the compute different logic.
Everything runs fine until I want to add a entrance to control which project to run. 
The destination is like 
/Project_Total 
    /Project_A 
    /Project_B 
    /main_total.py

Code in main_total.py is like:

```
from Project_A.main import main as main_a
from project_B.main import main as main_b


def which_to_run() -> bool:
    return True

def main():
    if which_to_run():
        main_a()
    else:
        main_b()
```

This is definitely can't work even i add both Project_A and Project_B into my PYTHONPATH, because they has same package name. 
My question is, how can I merge this two project, without changing code much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your solution is generally ok, the only think you need to change is importing methods inside the subprojects in relative fashion like that:

```
from .a import func

def main():
    func()
```